# How can you create a disk with an OS image in Azure from the command line?

Tags: azure, scripting, cloud

The command line tool in Azure allows you to create a disk from a .vhd image, like this

```
azure vm disk create my-data-disk ~/test.vhd --location "West US"
```

Instead of a local VHD, you can use one stored in a blob online, so if you've got one stuffed with your operating system of choice, you can just do that. However, I haven't found a way of creating it form one of the existing OS images in Azure or whether those images are stored in a blob and, if so, what's their address. Ultimately, what I want is to script the creation of a complete virtual machine in Azure, starting with storage; so far, I can script VM creation, but I have to create the disk storage from the control panel. 
I guess one of the options is to create the VM already provisioned from VMDepot https://vmdepot.msopentech.com but I would like to know if it's possible to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously need a virtual machine to store anything on a disk. So the right way to do this, online or via the command line, is to first create a virtual machine with the OS of your choice and with virtual storage attached, and then just delete the VM leaving the storage with your (least) favorite OS installed